# How to redirect API Management Developer portal URL to gateway url?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have setup a gateway url which points to my actual domain. But if users go to the developer portal URL, a basic blank page with a little info on API-M is shown. How do I redirect this page to the actual domain?

Comment: Do you want your API redirect to this gateway url type: <apim-service-name>.azure-api.net  ?

Comment: No I want the page under "Developer portal URL" (which can be found under the overview of the API-M instance) to redirect to portal homepage. Which happens to be the gateway url. I can't seem to find a place to edit this page. I'm on the old developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) > **API Management services** > Select your API Management service instance.
2. Under **Developer portal**, select **Identities** > Click on Add:
   Under  **Type**, select  **Azure Active Directory**  from the drop-down menu.

- Once selected, you'll be able to enter other necessary information.
- Information includes  **Client ID**  and  **Client secret**.

3. Save the **Redirect URL** for later.
   [image]

And the same redirect URL must be added in the app registry in the Azure AD.
To configure this, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad) for more detailed information.

Comment: I do not want to add AAD to the portal, so this isn't ideal. But if there is absolutely no other way then I will try this and accept it

Comment: Hello @ryansan - did you tried this solution, any update?