# azure-api-management different link to navigation items for different environments

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management

For our api management portal we have different environments, development to production. We create our pages in DEV and push them through with migrate via a pipeline.

For the sign up navigation item I am using a link to to open a account creation page on a self hosted website. For example, on development this links to 'dev.login.com'. For prod I want to link this to 'login.com'. Is this supported?

When I capture my api management with the capture script I can find my link in the snapshot data.json file

Comment: I understand you have 2 sign up pages based on environments. Are you looking for implementing redirection of user to approapriate sign-up url based on the environment?If so can you add the policies (if any) that you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As per our understanding, you want to create an API portal where the URL will be redirected to the login page with the different environments. Here is the example where you can use the redirection to login URL for which you need to create suffix as per the below image.

[image]

After creating API you need to add operation
[image]

Once the operation is created now by using [Return Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse) policy you can redirect the URL to the login page.

For complete information, you can go through the related discussions [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930603) and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/639629/azure-apim-redirect-url.html)